# Python - Print high if all word-comparisons are true

Tags: python

I have two strings:

`Rob car Mary bike George House Jerry Condo Risk High`

`Rob car Mary dc George dc Jerry dc`

First, I strip the first string of the last two words. I want to compare only words like `car`, `bike`, `house`, `condo` in string1 with words, such as `car`, `dc`, in string2. So, I created tuples `(car, car)`, (`bike, dc)`, `(house, dc)` and `(condo dc)`.

By comparing the words in the tuple, I need to either print `risk` as either `high` or `low`. Sometimes in the tuple, there is a `dc` present. This means that a `dc` can take any input such as `bike`, `house`, `condo`. I don't care about the word that is present at that point.

But, I only want to print the `risk` as `high` when both words in the tuple are `car`, i.e., `car == car`. Here, I am not concerned with the other tuples where there is a `dc` present because they can take any input. But, I do NOT want to print `high` when the words in the tuple are different `car` and `house`, i.e., `car != house`. Again, I am not concerned with a tuple where there is a `dc` because it can take any input.

To work on this, I wrote and tried this piece of code to do the comparison but, it failed and prints `high` for everything. For example,

I get `high` for these two strings when I use the code below:

`Rob house Mary bike George House Jerry Condo Risk High`

`Rob car Mary dc George dc Jerry dc`

This is because the words in the first tuple are (house, car) and `house != car`. 
What should I do to make it print the right value?

```
 def compareLines(devLine, f_hyp):
      global count 
      devSplit = devLine.split()

      risk_val = devSplit[-1]
      risk_attrib = devSplit[-2]
      devSplit = devSplit[:8]

      hypSplit = f_hyp.split()

      if all([(word1 == word2) or (word2 == 'dc') == True] for word1, word2 in zip(devSplit[1::2], hypSplit[1::2])):
           risk_setVal = "high"

           if risk_val != risk_setVal:
                count += 1

           print risk_setVal 

       else:
           risk_setVal =  "low"
           print risk_setVal
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what your rules for "high" are. Should each tuple be high or low, or are you generating one summary of all four tuples? Please revise your question with a clear explanation of what the different cases are, and ideally some more background information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated my post. Please let me know if this makes more sense. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `if all(...):` line. The comprehension inside `all(...)` will generate this for your sample input:

```
[[False], [True], [True], [True]]
```

This happens because you have wrapped `(word1 == word2) or (word2 == 'dc') == True` in square brackets, thus creating a list. However, any non-empty list evaluates to `True`, and so `all(...)` here will *always* evaluate to `True` because you're calling it on a list of non-empty lists.

Remove the square brackets from the comprehension inside `all(...)` and you should be good.

Comment: Oh wow! You are right! I can't believe I spent two hours on this! Thank YOU! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the case you are looking for is:

```
pairs = zip(devSplit[1::2], hypSplit[1::2])
if (any(a == "car" and b == "car" for a, b in pairs) and 
    all(a == b or b == "dc" for a, b in pairs)):
    print("High")
```

The first (`any`) check finds a pair of houses, the second (`all`) checks there are no mismatched pairs, unless the second half of the pair is `"dc"`.